# Questionable data on single channel satellite bands vs. RGB composites

Tags: python, gdal, sentinel-2, histogram

I am using Sentinel-2 images for a given region. I have all the separate bands and a merged RGB file, which comes standard with a download from ESA's API.

Now I'm running some code where I separate data into two folders. This means tiny cutouts of the satellite image, which are distributed into either folder 1 or folder 2.

Now I can construct a histogram of f.x. Sentinel-2 Band 04(Red Channel), where two curves illustrate the mean values of the small images in folder 1 and 2. This is presented as such:

[image: S2-Band 4 - Red]

I've done this across all single channel bands (Except 02, which for some yet unknown reason wont work)

Then I've also run the entirety of the merged RGB file which looks as this:
[image: S2-RGB Composite - Channel 4,3,2]

So here is my question! Why does the single channel 04 band look so different, in comparison to the merged second picture, where the bands are separated in the code. FYI: Band 3 is also off.

Side info: The data I'm using is from 2016, which is before ESA included a standard merge. So the merged RGB file I'm using have been created through the Gdal script of merging exactly channel 4,3,2 together, which looks like this:

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate stack.vrt B04.jp2 BO3.jp2 BO2.jp2
gdal_translate stack.vrt merged.tif
```

Comment: If you don't find an adequate answer here, consider cross-posting this question to https://earthscience.stackexchange.com

Comment: I wasn't aware of that site. Thanks @TrevorJ.Smith

Comment: Is the output RGB uint8 for display, while the input data is uint16?

Comment: @MarcPfister Good question, they have both been made to be "Byte" in Gdal (uint8)

Comment: What does `gdalinfo -mm B04.jp2` report for min/max?

Comment: @MarcPfister Band 1 Block=10980x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,255.000

Comment: And for the merged file: 

Band 1 Block=10980x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
    Computed Min/Max=3.000,255.000
Band 2 Block=10980x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
    Computed Min/Max=14.000,255.000
Band 3 Block=10980x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
    Computed Min/Max=28.000,255.000

Comment: And do I understand it right that `B04.jp2` is  subset you made? What does `gdalinfo -mm` report for the original image?

Comment: The first one i posted at 11:55, is the Single band channel on band 4, which I have converted to byte. The one that is still 16uint, gives the following:
Band 1 Block=10980x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
    Computed Min/Max=42.000,13845.000 @MarcPfister

Comment: If you look at pixel [1,1,1] in merged.tif does it have the same value as [1,1] in B04.jp2?